# Does OpenSL ES support PerformanceMode::LowLatency?

Tags: android, audio, oboe

When I build my app on a **Pixel 2 (Oreo 8.0)** I get PerformanceMode::LowLatency:

> 2019-06-30 15:04:15.560 8506-8506/? D/AUDIO-APP: HearSightEngine - Stream PlayStream IS low latency
>
> 2019-06-30 15:04:15.572 8506-8506/? D/AUDIO-APP: HearSightEngine - Stream Recording IS low latency

When I build my app on a **Samsung S7 (Nougat 7.0)** app I don't get it:

> 2019-06-30 14:49:30.874 20025-20025/? W/AUDIO-APP: HearSightEngine -
> Stream PlayStream is NOT low latency. Check your requested format,
> sample rate and channel count
>
> 2019-06-30 14:49:30.896 20025-20025/? W/AUDIO-APP: HearSightEngine -
> Stream Recording is NOT low latency. Check your requested format,
> sample rate and channel count

The two significant differences are

1. AAudio is used the first case and OpenSL ES is used in the second.
2. Pixel 2 is used in the first case, Samsung S7 is used in the
   second.

Does OpenSL ES support PerformanceMode::LowLatency? Or does Samsung S7 not support it? Or something else? I read the FAQ [1] and it mentioned AudioAttributes.FLAG_LOW_LATENCY for API's < 26, could something like that help me?

[1] https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md

Answer (score 1):

Only from Nougat 7.1 onwards. On previous versions of Android querying the performance mode will return `PerformanceMode::None`. [Here's the code](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/61a8c6de39b23feefc107cff4370c82ccc20ebcd/src/opensles/AudioStreamOpenSLES.cpp#L195).

There is no programmatic way to know whether you have a low latency stream on Android 7.0 and below. You can verify it manually using `adb shell dumpsys media.audio_flinger` and looking for the `F` (for FAST track) next to your app's stream.

You can maximise your chance of receiving a low latency stream by following the [guidance here](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md#obtaining-optimal-latency).